# php script doesn’t work well when called from html (jquery)

Tags: php, javascript, html5

I am creating a web page on a raspberry pi

Here is the essence of my html code:

```
<html><head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
        $("#test").load('climate.php') //load php result on the page
        }, 1000);
    });

</script>
</head>

<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
    <div id="test"></div>
</body></html>
```

I want to include some data from a text file using this php script :

```
<?php
    $filename = "/var/tmp/climate/save_climate.txt";
    if(file_exists($filename)){
      echo file_get_contents($filename);
    }
    else {
      echo 'could not find file'
    }
?>
```

My html and my php scripts work well, but there is an issue with the access to the file:

When I test my PHP script, he finds my file:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/HTML/home $ PHP climate.php
Temp=20.0*  Humidity=64.0%
```

But on the web page, this doesn’t work:

my **'could not find file'** message is displayed.

Is there someone with an explanation of what is happening here?

Thank you in advance!

Precisions:

- both my php script and my html are located in /var/www/html/home
- the text file is in /var/tmp/climate/save_climate.txt . He is updated every 10 min by cron, this is why he is not in the same directory.
- my website and my php script work well, the issue comes from somewhere else.
- my website is on a local network, completely hosted by my raspi.
- I’m on raspbian Buster

Comment: have your tried to call your php script from your browser, completely omitting the html and jquery part. also, does your webserver have the right to access the file. usually there is a user called www that executes your webserver.

Comment: I don’t manage to call and output the result of my php from my browser, bus it’s possible that my browser don't have access to the text file. How could I check that? And is there a way to access the content of a file somewhere else than the www directory?